# python removal of duplicate entries in list and print output of unique list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def rem_dups():
    output = []
    inpt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        for x in inpt:
            if x not in output:
            output.append()
    return output
```

So trying to figure out how to use my function above with 2 vars(output/input) where the input has the list of numbers and output is empty but at end should have list of unique numbers excluding any dup in the inpt list.  When i run this program i am getting "Process finished with exit code 0
" which i believe means program executed properly but not seeing any output from the return output at end of script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with your code.

1. You have to call the function in order to see any output.  Add `print(rem_dups())` at the end.
2. When you do, you will get a TypeError because you do not pass anything to the append method.  Change to `output.append(x)`
3. The algorithm you use is O(k*k) where k is the number of unique entries, because of the linear search in `x not in output`.  This is unnecessarily slow and will bite for large inputs.  Let us assume that you want output to be a list with order preserved.

Here is a fix.

```
def rem_dups():
    output = []
    uniques = set()
    inpt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for x in inpt:
        if x not in uniques:
            uniques.add(x)
            output.append(x)
    return output

print(rem_dups())
```

Answer (score 0):

inpt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
inpt=list(set(inpt))

this set() function removes dublicates

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about `Process finished with exit code 0`. That means your script was executed with no errors.

When running a script from the command line like so `$ python myscript.py`, the only output will be whatever is printed to stdout. Python's `return` doesn't return anything to the shell, it only works inside python.

Insted you can print to std that by simply calling `print(output)`, at the end of your script or main() function. (Or anywhere else)

Comment: Haken,  Thanks it works.  I found the set command and had it setup the same way but my issue was the output.append which wasn't in and didn't have any output.